# How to pass value from page to another page without using SESSION OR GET

Tags: php

`index.php page`  : here I want to display successfully added record message , coming from add.php page

`add.php  page`   : here I have written insert code , if data successfully inserted it will redirect to index.php page then message will be display on index.php page

But I dont want to pass in`$_SEESSION` or `$_GET` ,

Without `$_SEESSION` or `$_GET` is it possible ?

Comment: Why? HTTP is a stateless protocol, without session or get variables, you can't easily pass things between pages (unless you use one of the other HTTP verbs like post or put or some form of storage)

Comment: What is so bad about sessions? Chances are you already have one running, anyway. Might want to make use of it. Or just use `$_COOKIE` (hey, you didn't say those weren't allowed!)

Comment: is there a reason behind "I want"? The most natural way would be to use $_SESSION

Comment: My index.php : session_start(); echo $_SESSION['msg']; unset($_SESSION['msg']) , unset($_SESSION['msg'])  here because when user refresh page it should be eared automatically , But it is not working , I dont know why.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following methods:

1. Cookie
2. Database

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could store the data in the database before leaving the first page and then read it in the next page. I'm unsure why you'd want to make it this difficult, but it's a solution.

In fact, you might consider building a `Session` table in the database at this point:

```
CREATE TABLE Session (
    Id INT ...,
    UserName VARCHAR(...),
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME
);
```

and then create a `SessionState` table:

```
CREATE TABLE SessionState (
    Id INT ...,
    SessionId INT,
    VariableName VARCHAR(...),
    VariableValue VARCHAR(...)
);
```